# SQLServer Python Output

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm using Python in TSQL and trying to output data but getting the syntax error below. Any ideas?

```
execute sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

OutputDataSet = pd.DataFrame({ "id" : 1.})
'
with result sets ([id] int null);
```

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
    Incorrect syntax near 'id'.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I didn't realize that the results sets clause can have multiple result sets so you need use this syntax:

```
with result sets (([id] int null));
```

Then if you Python returns multiple sets:

```
with result sets ((A int null), (B int null), (C int null));
```